# Comparing Values

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a gaming program in Java and I'm comparing two variables.

```
int Pierce = 20;
int Defense = 50;
```

This is the if statement that compares the two.

```
if (Pierce > Defense)
{
    health = health - Pierce;
}
```

Of course health has already been initialized earlier in the program. So as you can see pierce is smaller than defense. In the game pierce should ALWAYS beat defense no matter the value. Is there some way to make this always true? I feel as if its something incredibly stupid, but I looked at all of the relational operators and they only seem to compare values, tests for equality, and for inequality.

Comment: If you ALWAYS want it to be true, why not just remove the if statement?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `if()` entirely:

```
health = health - pierce;
```

Or, if you are into shorthand:

```
health -= pierce;
```

Comment: Although wouldn't I need the if statement if I wanted it to recognize whenever defense was used? Sorry I guess I forgot to add that there are other spells.

Comment: Not really. Anywhere you would "use" defense you could put this statement. If you want an illustrative example, to make something ALWAYS test TRUE in an `if()` statement, use: `if(1) { thing(); }`

Comment: @L0j1k: In Java, you would need to use `if (true) { ...`

Answer (score -2):

Here is another answer:

```
if(health -= Pierce) {
  //Do something
}
```